# Returning a value based on qualification python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I am running through a pandas dataframe looking to pull the dates for when the max drawdown (dd) of an investment starts and ends. Below is what I have. I know that the logic of the for loop isn't correct yet, what I need help on is collecting date of the current row of the dataframe to a variable. I'm sure it's a pretty easy ask... just unsure how to do it. See all caps lines for where I need help. Thanks!

```
        len_dd = 0.0
        last_val = monthly_drawdown[-1]
        max_monthly_drawdown_ringer = 0 
        #For loop that goes through all the variables in monthly dd
        for val in muni['max_monthly_drawdown']:
            #If the current value is equal to the max dd...
            if val == max_monthly_drawdown:
                #Change the ringer to 1
                max_monthly_drawdown_ringer = 1
            #If the current month isn't a dd, and we just were in a dd 
            #that contained the max dd
            if val == 0.0 and len_dd > 0.0 and max_monthly_drawdown_ringer == 1:
                #collect end date and end the for loop
                endate = CODE HERE TO PULL muni['date'] FOR CURRENT ROW IN FOR LOOP
                break
            #If we are currently in a dd
            if val < 0.0:
                #Add one to length of drawdown
                len_dd = len_dd + 1
            #if we are at the start of the drawdown
            if val  < 0.0 and len_dd == 0:
                startdate = CODE HERE TO PULL muni['date'] FOR CURRENT ROW IN FOR LOOP
                len_dd = len_dd + 1
            #If we are on the last value and it's currently a dd that contains the
            #max dd    
            if val == last_val and last_val < 0.0 and max_monthly_drawdown_ringer == 1:
                #Collect date and end the for loop
                endate = CODE HERE TO PULL muni['date'] FOR CURRENT ROW IN FOR LOOP
            #If the current month isn't a dd
            if val == 0.0:
                #Reset len_dd to zero
                len_dd = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making this a method and use pandas apply.

For example:

```
df.apply(your_method, axis=1)
```

When you call apply with axis=1 your method will iterate over each record of the dataframe and have access to all of the current record's columns.

For example your method could be something like:

```
def your_method(record):
   if record.column_a == "some value":
       return record.column_b
   else:
       return record.column_c
```

You can read more about apply here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is not iterating over the rows of the dataframe - the code is looping over the values in one column and so the values in other columns are not directly available. If you are going to loop then it needs to be over the rows and you can then use the column values for each row as required. For example:

```
for row in muni.itertuples():
    val = row.max_monthly_drawdown
    # do whatever checks on val 
    val_date  = row.date    # this is the associated date
```

That said, if you have a large data file then it would be more efficient to use a vectorized approach rather than looping.